# I am trying to zip multiple pdf files and then upload them in S3 bucket

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, zip

I am able to zip pdfs and upload them in s3 bucket but PDFs are getting created in the project directory as well which I don't need. [PDFs are getting created like this. See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Fwgv.png)

```
    public void zipAndUploadToS3() throws IOException {
                    // Create a ByteArrayOutputStream to hold the zip data
                    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            
                    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);
                    
                    
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                        File pdfFile = new File(i + ".pdf");
            
                        // Create a new entry in the zip file for the PDF
                        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(pdfFile.getName());
            
                        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
InputStream fileInputStream = PdfService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(String.valueOf(accordFile));
            
                        if (fileInputStream == null) {
                            System.out.println(accordFile + " not found");
                        } else {
                            FileUtils.copyToFile(fileInputStream, pdfFile);
                        }
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        while ((len = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
            
                        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
            
                        fileInputStream.close();
                    }
            
                    zipOutputStream.close();
            
                    // Upload the zip file to S3
            
                    byte[] zipData = outputStream.toByteArray();
                    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                    metadata.setContentType("application/zip");
                    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, "my-zip-file.zip", new ByteArrayInputStream(zipData), metadata);
          s3client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
              s3client.setObjectAcl(bucketName, "my-zip-file.zip", CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
                    String objectUrl = s3client.getUrl(bucketName, "my-zip-file.zip").toString();
                    System.out.println(objectUrl);
                }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be copying pdf to file and using the same `fileInputStream` to output to zip - which will have read to the end.

Either try commenting out pdf writer part:

```
// FileUtils.copyToFile(fileInputStream, pdfFile);
```

..or if you want pdf then re-initialise the stream before you copy to `zipOutputStream`:

```
fileInputStream = PdfService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(String.valueOf(accordFile));
```